# PendingIntent with old extra and onCreate() don't call for singleTask Activity

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

My Single Task Activity is not created in a new task and onCreate is not called while I set the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in the intent. Then create the Pending intent with id 0 and PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT. What can I do?

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CommentPhotoActivity.class);

notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
notificationIntent.putExtra("posteid", pId);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = null;
//Preciser que La notif n'a pas été ouverte
//  session.createOpenNotifCmt(false);
if(pathImg.equals("")) {
      //  notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setContentTitle("Commentaire: " + emeteur).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(contentIntent).setContentText(cmt).setDeleteIntent(mBroadcastIntentController);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
           notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "my_channel_01");
           notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Commentaire: " + emeteur).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(contentIntent).setContentText(cmt);//.setDeleteIntent(mBroadcastIntentController);
    } else {
           notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setContentTitle("Commentaire: " + emeteur).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(contentIntent).setContentText(cmt);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Activities.CommentPhotoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_comment_photo"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">

    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".Services.SocketService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
```

When I click on notification and Activity is open I need to change the discussion(all discussions have same activity). To do that you have to go through onCreate.

CommentActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment_photo);

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        Log.v(TAG5,"onCreate");

     data = getIntent();

    mGroupManager = new GroupeManager(this);
    postemanager = new PosteManager(this);
    manager = new CommentManager(this);
    groupemanager = new GroupeManager(this);
    mixpanel = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(this, projectToken);
    session = new SessionManager(this);

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        Log.v(PosteAdapter.TAG1, "go discussion: ParcelableExtra" + data.getParcelableExtra("yuyu"));
    // Determiner la provenance de l intent pour extraire les données
    if (data.getParcelableExtra("yuyu") != null) {
        p = postemanager.getPostFromPostEmmetIdNew(((Poste) data.getParcelableExtra("yuyu")).getIdpostemet());
        poste_id = p.getId();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.v(PosteAdapter.TAG1, "go discussion: id=" + p.getId() + " Txt=" + p.getTx() + "IdPostEmet" + p.getIdpostemet());

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.v(TAG6, "POST"+p.getTx()+"POST STATE READ: " + p.getVisited());
        }
    } else {
        //Notif Open
    //    session.createOpenNotifCmt(true);
        poste_id = data.getIntExtra("posteid", 0);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.v(SocketService.TAG2, "2: posteid" + data.getIntExtra("posteid", 0));
        }
        p = postemanager.getPost(poste_id);
    }


      ....................

    contactmanager = new ContactManager(this);
    manager = new CommentManager(this);
    allComments = manager.getAllComments(poste_id);
    adapter = new CommentAdapter(this, allComments);

    listCmtView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    listCmtView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listCmtView.setItemViewCacheSize(10);
    listCmtView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    listCmtView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);

    listCmtView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

    }
```

Comment: Please post your manifest

Comment: I've added the manifest to the original post.

Comment: I'm confused about what your problem is.  You've created a `Notification` that will start your `Activity` when clicked. If the `Activity` is already running it will simply be brought to the front (and `onCreate()` will not be called, but `onNewIntent()` should be called.)

Comment: When I click on notification and Activity is open I need to change the discussion(all discussions have same activity). To do that you have to go through onCreate.

Comment: I found solution I add this ' notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;' and I differenciate ID_NOTIF

Comment: I have always problem for android Oreo

Comment: Did you override `onNewIntent()` and see if that is getting called?

Comment: onNewIntent() is called only for android Oreo

Comment: I rewrite onCreate code in onNewIntent Thanks

Comment: `onNewIntent()` should be called on all versions of Android.

Comment: so that's not normal, in my code onNewIntent() is called only on Oreo

Comment: so in non-Oreo, `onCreate()` is being called again? But this means that the existing `Activity` is killed (`onDestroy()` is called) and then a new instance of the `Activity` is created (`onCreate()` is called)?

Comment: Do you have multiple activities in your app?

Comment: Yes I have multiple activity. In non-Oreo, onCreate and onDestroy() is being called. So my problem is solved, In Oreo I use onNewIntent() and in non-Oreo I use onCreate. Thank you so much

Comment: I'm glad your problem is solved, but the explanation makes no sense. But if you don't want to invest any more time on it, I understand.

Comment: Why not, may be I will understand more. But I do not know what to do to understand this behavior